# search lines of text file for a value and show results over a certain number

Tags: linux, search, grep

I have a text file in this format:

address,name,name2,count,junk

I want to search (using regex or grep on linux) for lines that "count" are over a certain amount.

Is this possible?

If not, I guess I have to load the data into mysql so I can run the query.

Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output and your attempt to solve the problem yourself so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with `awk`:

```bash
awk -F ',' '{ if($4 > 10) {print $0}}' my_text_file
```

`-F ','` - this is field separator used to break each line into fields.

`if($4 > 10) {...}` we are checking here if field number four ($4) has value greater than 10.

`$0` - variable holding the entire line

If your csv contains more complex fields like: "1234 A Pretty Street, NE" you have to use `gawk` `FPAT` variable [FPAT](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Splitting-By-Content).

```bash
awk 'BEGIN{ FPAT="([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")"} { if($4 > 10) {print $0}}' my_text_file
```

Comment: This works great, thank you, except on any of the lines that don't have "s around name field, didn't spot those until i ran this - any workaround for that?

Comment: i added  | grep -v \"

Comment: The reason for the "-ed entries is they have a , within them

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand it correctly, can you provide some example lines from the file?

Comment: john@smith.com,"smith, john",johnsmith,50,100       any name field without a comma is not in quotes

Comment: I edited my answer, now it can handle your case

Comment: `'{ if($4 > 10) {print $0}}'` = `'$4 > 10'`.